# Lock git branch : Bitbucket + hubot

Tags: git, bitbucket, hubot, bitbucket-api

I have Bitbucket and using it I can lock git branches like so:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html

my question is how can I automate this task using Hubot script ?
is there any API i can use?
only found https://www.npmjs.com/package/hubot-bitbucket which can listen to pull and push requests

Answer (score 1):

found this url for managing branch permissions using API: 
https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/2.12.1/stash-branch-permissions-rest.html